# Comparing two list of objects and forming a new list by comparing one property of two list in java 8

Tags: java, list, java-stream

I have two list of objects. And this lists of objects have a common property(eg : Id). I would like to check if the property value ie; id of first list and second list is equal and if equal, then create a new list with only the objects having  the same property value using java 8.

I have tried using two for loops. But I want to have the solution in java 8

Comment: Please, post your code with the loops.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want intersection of the list while saving of first list type.

Get the common field values in the Set.

```
valuesToCheck=secondList.stream().map(SecondListObject::commonFiled).collect(Collectors.toList);
```

'''

Apply a stream on the first while filtering based on the matching common field value in the set built in the previous step.

```
firstList.stream().filter(x->valuesToCheck.contains(x.getCommonFiled)).collect(toList)
```

You got the gist.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is what I was looking for :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is one possible solution.  (Not tested.)

Assuming that the lists are are random access and the same length, and that neither the list elements or the properties are `null`:

```
List<SomeType> list1 = ...
List<SomeType> list2 = ...
List<SomeType> res =
    IntStream.range(0, list1.size())
    .filter(i -> list1.get(i).getSomeProp().equals(list2.get(i).getSomeProp()))
    .map(i -> list1.get(i))
    .Collectors.toList();
```

(This will also work if the lists aren't random access, but it will be `O(N^2)`.)

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have my first list say one object and second list is another type of object. The third list  I have form should be the list of object(similar to first list).For example : I have a list 1 with List<Abcbean>xyz=new ArrayList<>() and list 2 with List<Abcbean>opl=new ArrayList<>() . Both these have a property uniqueId. I need the third list as a list of Abcbean hich has uniqueId equal in both the list. My third list should be like : List<Abcbean>lkj=new ArrayList<>(); Please help me

Comment: Above option i tired and Im getting error. Error : Type mismatch: cannot convert from xyzbean ( third list object) to int.Please help me